# Serialize all embedded resources in python-eve query recursively

Tags: python, mongodb, serialization, embedded-resource, eve

I have an [Python-Eve](http://python-eve.org/)-API to a MongoDB which is able to serialize embedded resources as described in the [docs](http://python-eve.org/features.html#embedded-resource-serialization).

In my case the request `http://127.0.0.1:5000/sectors` leads to the following response (not serializing embedded resources):

```
{
    "_items": [
        {
            "mflow_fluid": 0.23,
            "_id": "562692d055c40f709ce289d5",
            "inlet_top": true,
            "inlet_temp": 353,
            "_etag": "53c3d9b10fc2bdcc4f68c7ed07d3ba13f57ca252",
            "_created": "Tue, 20 Oct 2015 19:15:28 GMT",
            "_updated": "Tue, 20 Oct 2015 19:15:28 GMT",
            "name": "sector_heating",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "title": "Sector",
                    "href": "sectors/562692d055c40f709ce289d5"
                }
            },
            "angle_deg": 180,
            "fluid": "562692d055c40f709ce289d4"
        },
        {
            "mflow_fluid": 0.46,
            "_id": "562692d055c40f709ce289d6",
            "inlet_top": true,
            "inlet_temp": 283,
            "_etag": "0aaf153ff7417cde03bacb0601c5ee244d173cfe",
            "_created": "Tue, 20 Oct 2015 19:15:28 GMT",
            "_updated": "Tue, 20 Oct 2015 19:15:28 GMT",
            "name": "sector_cooling",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "title": "Sector",
                    "href": "sectors/562692d055c40f709ce289d6"
                }
            },
            "angle_deg": 180,
            "fluid": "562692d055c40f709ce289d4"
        }
    ],
    "_meta": {
        "page": 1,
        "max_results": 25,
        "total": 2
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "title": "sectors",
            "href": "sectors"
        },
        "parent": {
            "title": "home",
            "href": "/"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the key `fluid` contains an embedded resource, which can be serialized using a request like `http://127.0.0.1:5000/sectors?embedded={"fluid":1}`, giving the following response:

```
{
    "_items": [
        {
            "mflow_fluid": 0.23,
            "_id": "562692d055c40f709ce289d5",
            "inlet_top": true,
            "inlet_temp": 353,
            "_etag": "53c3d9b10fc2bdcc4f68c7ed07d3ba13f57ca252",
            "_created": "Tue, 20 Oct 2015 19:15:28 GMT",
            "_updated": "Tue, 20 Oct 2015 19:15:28 GMT",
            "name": "sector_heating",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "title": "Sector",
                    "href": "sectors/562692d055c40f709ce289d5"
                }
            },
            "angle_deg": 180,
            "fluid": {
                "specific_heat": 1005,
                "_id": "562692d055c40f709ce289d4",
                "specific_gas_constant": 287.12,
                "_etag": "7c9c9c1d5e5dfe5414068d0a12736a1721d05926",
                "name": "air",
                "_updated": "Tue, 20 Oct 2015 19:15:28 GMT",
                "composition": [
                    {
                        "fraction": 0.79,
                        "component": "562692cf55c40f709ce289d2"
                    },
                    {
                        "fraction": 0.21,
                        "component": "562692d055c40f709ce289d3"
                    }
                ],
                "state": "gaseous",
                "_created": "Tue, 20 Oct 2015 19:15:28 GMT"
            }
        },
        {
            "mflow_fluid": 0.46,
            "_id": "562692d055c40f709ce289d6",
            "inlet_top": true,
            "inlet_temp": 283,
            "_etag": "0aaf153ff7417cde03bacb0601c5ee244d173cfe",
            "_created": "Tue, 20 Oct 2015 19:15:28 GMT",
            "_updated": "Tue, 20 Oct 2015 19:15:28 GMT",
            "name": "sector_cooling",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "title": "Sector",
                    "href": "sectors/562692d055c40f709ce289d6"
                }
            },
            "angle_deg": 180,
            "fluid": {
                "specific_heat": 1005,
                "_id": "562692d055c40f709ce289d4",
                "specific_gas_constant": 287.12,
                "_etag": "7c9c9c1d5e5dfe5414068d0a12736a1721d05926",
                "name": "air",
                "_updated": "Tue, 20 Oct 2015 19:15:28 GMT",
                "composition": [
                    {
                        "fraction": 0.79,
                        "component": "562692cf55c40f709ce289d2"
                    },
                    {
                        "fraction": 0.21,
                        "component": "562692d055c40f709ce289d3"
                    }
                ],
                "state": "gaseous",
                "_created": "Tue, 20 Oct 2015 19:15:28 GMT"
            }
        }
    ],
    "_meta": {
        "page": 1,
        "max_results": 25,
        "total": 2
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "title": "sectors",
            "href": "sectors"
        },
        "parent": {
            "title": "home",
            "href": "/"
        }
    }
}
```

The embedded resource for the key `fluid` is serialized as desired. However, this resource contains another embedded resource for the key `component` in the `composition` resource of `fluid`.

Is there a way to serialize all embedded resources 'recursively' in order to get a fully serialized resource as a response?

I tried to do something like `http://127.0.0.1:5000/sectors?embedded={"fluid":1 "fluid.composition.component":1}` leading to a 400-response:

```
{
  "_error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Unable to parse `embedded` clause"
  },
  "_status": "ERR"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that's not currently supported. Embedded resource serialisation currently supports nested resources, but has some [limitations](http://python-eve.org/features#limitations):

> Currently we support embedding of documents by references located in any subdocuments (nested dicts and lists). For example, a query /invoices?/embedded={"user.friends":1} will return a document with user and all his friends embedded, but only if user is a subdocument and friends is a list of reference (it could be a list of dicts, nested dict, etc.)